# Create a "view" of a Java List

Tags: java, list

When doing something like

```
// creating list1, adding items
LinkedList slist = new LinkedList();
slist = subList(list1, 2,5);
```

I will have a second object (a "copy" of the elements 2 to 5 of "list") returned by subList and contained in slist.
However, I would like to have something that only gives me a "view" of list1, without creating a new object and without allocating new memory, for performance/memory reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think [List#subList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) does exactly what you want:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

```
List slist = list1.subList(2, 5);
```

Of course, a new (wrapper) object needs to be created, but the data structure for the list, and all the elements will be re-used. The wrapper just keeps track of the start and end pointers.

Comment: Ah, so creating "slist" will only create a wrapper object?

Comment: Yes, `slist` will need to have some memory allocated for it, but it does not maintain a copy of the original list, just pointers into it.

Comment: and this portion of allocated memory will not be very large compared to the list, right? it will probably only contain the "first" and "last" references of the sublist.

Comment: You need to create new object if u want to take sublist form original List .

Comment: yes, that's right. The JavaDocs even go so far as to say "This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list. ", implying that there are no performance issues.

Comment: and how can I cast this new subList to e.g. a LinkedList? doing something like <code>List slist = (LinkedList) list2.subList(0, 1);</code> tells me that I can't cast subList to LinkedList. Will subList automatically return a list of the type of list1?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it to `LinkedList`? And no, it is not a `LinkedList`, it is a `java.util.SubList`, which is a private utility class.

Comment: It turned out, that I don't need to cast it to LinkedList. However, there might be cases, where you would like to have operations like slist.getLast(), which you can only call on a LinkedList. How would I handle these cases with a list of type subList?

Comment: Looking at the source code, calling `sublist.get(sublist.size()-1)` will still use the efficient tail pointer of the linked list under the hood. So you lose nothing performance-wise, but you might miss the convenient interface `getLast()`.

Comment: "sublist will still use the efficient tail pointer of the linked list under the hood" Okay, clarification, this only works if the end of sublist aligns with the end of the full list (or is at least close to it). There is no extra pointer to the end (or start) of the sublist, it is all index-based, which might get slow for sublists from the middle of a long linked list. For random access, use an ArrayList instead.